# Peculiar Strong Law of Large Numbers: Why this formulation?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading a book that defines the SLLN as:

$$P\left(\limsup_{n->\infty} \left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-E(X_i))\right|=0\right)=1$$

My doubt is why the lim sup, and not just the lim? Also, I assume he writes the expected value inside the sum to allow for not identically distributed r.v.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do we expect the limit to exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence may not have a limit at all, which would lead to a problem of what it means to write a probability for an event whose defining formula is not even defined for some outcomes. On the other hand the limes superior always exists (though it may be $\infty$) avoiding that problem.